Triangle is not rendering
I wrote a simple program using the glFrustum function. All points of the triangle are within range, but it doesn't appear.
glewInit();
sf::Window window(sf::VideoMode(800, 800), "OpenGL", sf::Style::Default, sf::ContextSettings(32));
window.setVerticalSyncEnabled(true);
// activate the window
window.setActive(true);
bool running = true;   
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glFrustum(-5.0, 5.0, -5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 10);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();

while (running)
{
    ........//event process
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glColor3f(0.1, 0.7, 0.2);
    glVertex3f(0, 0, -5);
    glVertex3f(2, 2, -5);
    glVertex3f(3, 3, -5);
    glEnd();

    window.display();
}


The problem is that these three vertices (0, 0, -5), (2, 2, -5) and (3, 3, -5) don't form a triangle. These are collinear, i.e. these three points lie on a line.
You could, for example, change the middle vertex to (2, 0, -5) and a triangle will render:


@Shellong I think that that boils down to an equals-comparison between two (finite precision) floating point numbers, which is best avoided. You could see what glFrustum actually computes when this matrix is multiplied with the vector. In practice, it's best to set the near plane slightly closer to what would be needed mathematically. Same for the far plane.
